# Push Data to JavaScript Function Called with onClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a JavaScript function that is called on an event. It looks like this:

```
function showArrays(event) {
  // Taken from Google Maps API Documentation 
  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
  // MVCArray of LatLngs.
  var vertices = this.getPath();
  var contentString = 'A';

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

I call this function from a previous JavaScript Function in the same file. I call it using this code:

```
function initMap(){
  var myString = 'abc';
  region.addListener('click', showArrays);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}
```

I want to also pass 'myString' to showArrays so 'contentString' can be set to its value. However, I'm not really sure how I could push the data between the functions. I've tried to edit showArrays to take both an event parameter and a data parameter, but this doesn't work, perhaps because my syntax is wrong. Any ideas how I could do this? Perhaps with JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showArrays(event,_str) {
  // Taken from Google Maps API Documentation 
  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
  // MVCArray of LatLngs.
  var vertices = this.getPath();
  var contentString = 'A';

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString+_str);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}

function initMap(){
  var myString = 'abc';
  region.addListener('click', function(event){
   showArrays(event, 'myString' )
   });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
}
```

Do like that call a callback function and callback function will fire showArrays with object

```
region.addListener('click', function(event){
   showArrays(event, 'myString' )
   });
```

Comment: Where does myString fit into your response?

Comment: How I am doing check

Comment: I am just explaining how can you pass arguments into callback function

Comment: Everything works except the popup window reads 'myString' instead of the value of 'myString'

Comment: Your question was how to pass argument in call back function and now you are saying my popup is not working.

Comment: Please provide detail what you want to do

Comment: I want to pass the value of myString (so 'abc') to the showArrays() function, and set the value of contentString equal to the value of myString.

Comment: Then where is the problem

Comment: Try **var contentString =_str**

Comment: Use my example as I have given above. and then press CTRL+F5 and try